# What is the actual meaning of Soundproofing?

Tags: meaning

> This room is a soundproofing room.

Which means,

1. When you are in the inside room, you won't hear outside sounds.
2. When you are in outside, you won't hear sounds generated by inside
   room
3. Both

Comment: Are you sure that it wasn't "a **soundproof** room"?

Comment: Agree with @Laurel .  a soundproof room. or a soundproofed room (one that has been made soundproof)  A soundproofing room in my mind is one where soundproofing is performed.  Or a room where soundproofing (the material used to soundproof something) is kept.

Comment: @Jim I copied this from a magazine. I don't know that whthere it is a typo or not from their end.

Comment: A "soundproofing room" is a room where you install soundproofing to objects (temporarily) in the room.

Answer (score -1):

It can be used in both contexts depending on the way it is implemented. In Wikipedia you can find examples like [Room within a room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundproofing#Room_within_a_room) (1) and [Residential soundproofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundproofing#Residential_soundproofing) (2). Materials and installation could be different in both cases, but the term "soundproofing" should be also used in a more general case (3).